# Optional but not included trailing shash?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

How to make last slash optional, but not included in the result?

```
RewriteRule ^page\/(.+)[^/]$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Right now those return as follow. but I really don't want the slash:

```
/page/download/ - returns 'download/'
/page/download  - returns 'download'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in your pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.+?)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or else use this pattern if you just want to match `/path/abc` OR `/path/abc/`:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```